# function() exists but prototype function() doesn't exist. Why?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype-programming

I am creating a JavaScript class called ImageRotatorManager to manage a dynamically-loaded slideshow.  When loading the images via xml, I have the following functions defined:

```
/* Loads configuration settings for the image rotator */
ImageRotatorManager.prototype.loadXML = function (callback) {
    jQuery.get("assets/image-rotator.xml", {}, function (xml) {
            parseXML(xml, callback); //the callback function                                             
    });
};

/* Loads configuration settings for the image rotator */
function parseXML(xml, callback) {
    //find every image and add the image to the '#slideshow' div
};
```

the function `parseXML(xml, callback)` is called successfully.

However if I define parseXML() as `ImageRotatorManager.prototype.parseXML = function (xml, callback)` and call this function using `ImageRotatorManager.parseXML(xml, callback);`, I receive the following error:

> ImageRotatorManager.parseXML is not a function

Why do I get this error?  I make other function calls using this signature and they work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `.parseXML()` that way.

You've added it to the *prototype* so you must call it on an *instance* of the class, not using the class name itself.

Try this:

```
ImageRotatorManager.prototype.loadXML = function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    jQuery.get("assets/image-rotator.xml", {}, function (xml) {
        self.parseXML(xml, callback); //the callback function
    });
};
```

Comment: I've tried calling `this.parseXML()` as well, but this doesn't solve my problem either.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Kyle: Be carful with `this`. What it refers to depends on the context.

Comment: @Kyle see update - `this` inside the `.get()` callback will have changed.

Comment: Brilliant!  You're absolutely right, `this` changes within the anonymous function.  Thanks -

Comment: @Kyle you're welcome.  FWIW, `this` changes in _every_ function call.

Answer (score 1):

Can you assign `parseXML()` directly to `ImageRotatorManager`?

```
ImageRotatorManager.parseXML = function(xml, callback) { ... };
```

and call it like you would a static method in Java?

```
ImageRotatorManager.parseXML(xml, callback);
```

Comment: that could work, but the real issue here is how to call between _prototyped_ methods of the same class.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the suggestion.  I like the answer above better, simply because it eliminates the need for static functions.